# Changing default django admin widget site wide

Tags: python, django

I want to modify the widget used by `models.URLField` to include a dropdown with internal links in my site (similar to [`any-urlfield`](https://github.com/edoburu/django-any-urlfield) but detected from the sitemap).

I want to have every external app that uses a `models.URLField` use this custom widget and not have to redefine each individual app `formfield_overrides`.

I looked into `django/contrib/admin/options.py` and found

```
FORMFIELD_FOR_DBFIELD_DEFAULTS = {
 ...
 models.TextField: {'widget': widgets.AdminTextareaWidget},
 models.URLField: {'widget': widgets.AdminURLFieldWidget},
 models.IntegerField: {'widget': widgets.AdminIntegerFieldWidget},
 models.BigIntegerField: {'widget': widgets.AdminBigIntegerFieldWidget},
 ...
}
```

Essentially I would like to change this default if it were possible. How would I go about changing the default widget for a field in the django admin site wide.

Comment: Makes no sense at all why this question just got downvoted

Comment: Obviously someone hates me :P Since it's a useful question and has a great answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not to update this dictionary?  Place this code to any `admin.py` file.

```
from django.contrib.admin import options
from django.db import models
from django.forms import widgets

options.FORMFIELD_FOR_DBFIELD_DEFAULTS[models.URLField] = {
                                           'widget': widgets.TextInput}
```

**UPDATE**: To make this work you should place this line at the top of the `admin.py` before any `admin.site.register()` calls.  Also you need to move the app with such `admin.py` somewhere at top of the `INSTALLED_APPS` list.  This change will affect all apps loaded after the mentioned app.

Comment: I don't want to put it into an admin.py for an individual app. I want it to apply to all apps as I said in the question and this doesn't work.

Comment: This answer helped to get me to the right place, albeit a completely different solution for my purposes.  I just wanted the URL to open in a new tab so added a copy of the `admin/widgets/url.html` template in my own templates directory and edited that.  Hope this helps someone!